# Issue with unique_ptr

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me what the issue is with this code? It throws an error:

> cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const day18::BaseInstruction &'

```
    enum Command { snd, set, add, mul, mod, rcv, jgz };
    struct BaseInstruction {
        Command cmd;
        char reg;
        BaseInstruction(Command cmd, char reg)
            :cmd{cmd}, reg{reg}
        {}
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct Instruction : public BaseInstruction {
        T val;
        Instruction(Command cmd, char reg, T val)
            :BaseInstruction(cmd, reg), val{ val }
        {}
    };
    std::unique_ptr<BaseInstruction> getInstructionPtr(Command cmd, char reg, std::string valStr) {
        const static std::regex nr("-?\\d+");
        if (valStr.length() == 0) return std::make_unique<BaseInstruction>(new BaseInstruction(cmd, reg));
        if (std::regex_match(valStr, nr)) return std::make_unique<BaseInstruction>(new Instruction<int>(cmd, reg, std::stoi(valStr)));
        return std::make_unique<BaseInstruction>(new Instruction<char>(cmd, reg, valStr[0]));
    }
```

Comment: `return std::make_unique<Instruction<char>>(cmd, reg, valStr[0]);` (for example)

Comment: Oh, and add a `virtual` destructor to your `BaseInstruction` class to make it properly polymorphic (which I guess would be a good idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::make_unique()` is the smart-pointer equivalent of `new`, which means it calls the constructor of the specified type, passing the input parameters to that constructor, and returns a `std::unique_ptr` that points to the new object.

The statement:

```
std::make_unique<BaseInstruction>(new Instruction<char>(...));
```

is therefore equivalent to this:

```
new BaseInstruction(new Instruction<char>(...))
```

I'm quite sure that's not what you meant to write.

If you just want to convert a raw pointer to a `std::unique_ptr`, *construct* the `std::unique_ptr` directly and don't use `std::make_unique()`:

```
return std::unique_ptr<BaseInstruction>(new Instruction<char>(...));
```

Otherwise, use `std::make_unique()` to construct `Instruction<char>` instead of `BaseInstruction`:

```
return std::make_unique<Instruction<char>>(...);
```

Comment: Why not use `make_unique` like mentioned in the comment above (@Someprogrammerdude) ? Isn't it better than using a raw `new` ?